# installation fails trying to fix dependencies

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know what to do. everytime I try to use "sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full", terminal tells me there were unfulfilled dependencies. However, I did not set any of these and I do not know how to remove them. Nevertheless, I really need to install ROS...
Do you know what I can change in order to make it work?
Thank you very much!

PS:
the problem appears in this step:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

(as one of them did not work, I tried the other one, too. My ubuntu version is 15.04).

The error messages:

```
E: Paket xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libgbm-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

("kan nicht gefunden werden" means "cannot be found").
I do not know why this happens. I my settings for "Software and Updates" for "download from" is "main server" (changing it to German server does not change anything). Of course, I have also done each of the first steps described in the download tutorial. I am sure that I did not type in anything wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218489/installation-fails-trying-to-fix-dependencies/) by [juwinkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/24172/juwinkler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-01**:
Please copy/paste the exact errors into your question (use the *edit* button/link for that). Without information we cannot help you. Please format error text using the *Preformatted text* button on the toolbar (it's the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [juwinkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/24172/juwinkler/) on 2015-10-04**:
Okay, thank you, I edited the post :)
Do you have an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be following these insructions: http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu

The section you're following is for 14.04.2 only.  You can skip that on 15.04

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juwinkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/24172/juwinkler/) on 2015-10-15**:
yes, I follow the instructions.
if I do not follow them and start to install ros, it does not work.
also, i cannot install it by klicking on installing when I use the non-terminal method.
an error message says that there are dependency problems. thus, i conclude, i do have to fix them... :/

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-10-15**:
You have provided the console output from the part you don't need to do, but have not provided details on the later message. Please provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem and see exactly what you're typing and getting as an output for us to be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not install ros-indigo , have a try.
if you really don't how to solve this problem . as you said you cannot remove them too, why not reinstall your system?
That sounds like a crazy thing but will save a lot time for you.

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1